# output audio to usb on djm2000 mixer

Tags: usb, sound

I am unable to output audio onto my djm 2000 mixer via usb.

I have followed this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices

```
juddy@T3500-Ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf7ffc000 irq 28
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7cfc000 irq 29
 2 [DJM2000        ]: USB-Audio - DJM-2000
                      Pioneer DJM-2000 at usb-0000:00:1d.2-1, full speed
```

---

```
juddy@T3500-Ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 08e4:014d Pioneer Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The tutorial advises to edit */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base*

I done this and added:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias snd-card-1 snd-hda-nvidia
alias snd-card-2 snd-usb-audio
```

But I still can't pick the djm2000 an an output source. I have 2 input sources since adding the lines to the conf file when originally I only had one. The original one was DJM2000 analouge input and now i have digital input too via S/PDIF

Just to be clear exactly what I am trying to do here. I am trying to output audio via usb cable from my dell precision t3500 to my pioneer DJM2000 so that I can listen to music through my studio monitors via a good soundcard. The sound I have at the moment is only through HDMI on my TV and I need audio through the DJM 2000 soundcard.

Hope this makes sense, bit of a Ubuntu newb :)

Comment: Your manual says: *This driver software is a **proprietary** program for inputting and outputting audio signals from the computer. To use this unit connected to a computer on which a **Windows** or **Mac OS** is installed, install the driver software on the computer beforehand.*

Comment: yeah ok I get that... I can use it on windows and mac, which works a treat.... but audio output is impossible in ubuntu? input to this soundcard seems ok? so should I just give up?

Comment: The problem is always the same with all things "proprietary"... Either the manufacturer releases a Linux native version or the "community" comes up with an alternative, independently developed.

Comment: ok doubt pioneer will come up with a linux driver, its not widely enough used... I'm just using headphones at the moment so i guess that will have to do....